# Sort couple array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a "Couple" class with nothing more special than a String and a double:

```
public class Couple{

public String mot;
public double indice;

public Couple(){
    this.mot = "";
    this.indice = 0;
}

public Couple(String t, double q){
    this.mot = t;
    this.indice = q;
}
}
```

Now, suppose I have an array of Couple.
I want to sort that array by the double from each value.
For example:

Before sorting :

{("hi",3), ("hello",1),("Good",2),("nice",0)}

After sorting according to the double values of each couple:

{("nice",0),("hello",1),("Good",2),("hi",3)}

Comment: There are multiple ways. What did you **try**? What research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

use `implements Comparable` for couple class , override `compareTo` and then sort with  `Collections.sort();`

```
public class Couple implements Comparable<Couple>{

public String mot;
public double indice;

public Couple(){
    this.mot = "";
    this.indice = 0;
}

public Couple(String t, double q){
    this.mot = t;
    this.indice = q;
}

public int compareTo(Couple obj)
{
    return (int)(indice);
}
}
```